# How do I generate a sequence of integer numbers in a uniform distribution?

Tags: python, random

I want to generate 4 random integer numbers in the range `[1,4]` in a uniform distribution. For example, each number appears 3 times for a sequence of 12 elements.

Comment: That wouldn't be random :/

Comment: How do you define "appear equally"? Do you mean [uniform distrubution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29)?

Comment: @linusg the issue is probably that they would want to generate a sequence of arbitrary length which had elements in a random order, in which each element is equally likely to appear. I used something similar in A/B testing: I needed a fixed percentage of people across the whole test to receive SMS A, but the total pool of people in the test was variable. You can see my answer for an example. The choice of SMS for any one person was randomised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a generator:

```
from random import randint

def getNum1To4(runs):
    occurences = {n+1:0 for n in range(4)}
    for i in range(runs):
        options = [n for n in occurences if occurences[n] < runs / 4]
        choice = options[randint(0, len(options) - 1)]
        occurences[choice] += 1
        yield choice
```

outputs:

```
>>> runs = 8
>>> gen = getNum1To4(8)
>>> for n in range(runs): print gen.next()
2
1
3
1
3
4
4
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lists for this task to ensure that your pool of available numbers does not include any duplicates. I'm not sure if you need them to appear in set blocks within the list of 12 or whether you want it fully randomised. If the former, remove the last shuffle.

```
from random import shuffle

choice_pool = [x for x in range(1, 5)]
random_output = []
number_of_runs = 4

for x in range(number_of_runs):
    shuffle(choice_pool)
    random_output += choice_pool

shuffle(random_output)
print random_output
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach should work:

```
import random

foo = [i for i in range(1, 5)] * 4
print random.sample(foo, len(foo))
```

Output: `[2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out -

```
import random

def foo(number_of_runs, lower_limit, upper_limit):
    turns = number_of_runs // (upper_limit - lower_limit + 1)
    arr = list(range(lower_limit, upper_limit + 1)) * turns
    random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr

print(foo(12, 1, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import random 
x = [i for i in range(1, 5)] * 3 
random.shuffle(x) # shuffle the sequence x in place

# Output
[4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1]
```

---

If the elements are float or double, the answer would be much easier by using [numpy.random.uniform](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html#numpy-random-uniform)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.uniform(1, 5, 12)

# Output
array([ 4.18515267,  4.87403138,  3.43580119,  2.62828693,  3.77675348,
        4.15627119,  4.02190688,  3.56667674,  1.31115154,  1.74971624,
        3.20515834,  1.75240044])
```

Answer (score 0):

For generating random integers from "Uniform random distribution" in the given range [1,50] with size of 5 let say,

```
from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint

values = sp_randint.rvs(1, 50, size=5, random_state=0)

print(values)
```

Output:

```
[94 97 50 53 53]
```

Please note `random_state=0` is necessary to write otherwise it will give you random output at each run. For more details, check out [documentation.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.randint.html)